# How are the "Library Directories" under "VC++ Directories" passed to the linker in Visual Studio C++ projects?

Tags: visual-c++, linker, visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio (2019) C++ projects, the project properties window has a "VC++ Directories" section.  There you can add "Library Directories" that are presumably directories the linker looks for .lib files referenced in the project when linking.  I'm trying to troubleshoot a problem where the linker seems not to be finding a .lib file that's in one of the directories listed under "Library Directories".  I'd like to know how the linker is made aware of those directories so I know where to look for my problem.  Under "Linker->Command Line", none of those directories show up, so I'm thinking maybe they're passed in an environment variable?

**Edit:** I found the answer to the above part of the question just now and self-answered.  Here's my remaining question:

Is there any way I can get ahold of the value of the LIB variable at the moment MSBuild invokes the linker?  I guess I'm mostly looking for a sanity check at this point.

**Edit:** I found the answer to this part too.  Is this a junk question at this point?  I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer to the stupid part of my question from Visual Studio's UI:

When you select "Library Directories" in the "VC++ Directories" pane, the help text at the bottom of the screen says:

**Library Directories**
Path to use when searching for library files while building a VC++ project.  Corresponds to the environment variable LIB.

**Edit:** Regarding the second part of my question, I looked into MSBuild command line arguments and learned that I can try to build the solution at the command line with -verbosity:d (for detailed) which prints the values of all the SetEnv commands.